# How to change parameters of a scikit learn function dynamically i.e. find best parameter

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to do dimensionality reduction using PCA function of sklearn, specifically

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

def mypca(X,comp): 
pca = PCA(n_components=comp)
pca.fit(X)
PCA(copy=True, n_components=comp, whiten=False)
Xpca = pca.fit_transform(X)
return Xpca

for n_comp in range(10,1000,20):
    Xpca = mypca(X,n_comp) # X is a 2 dimensional array
    print Xpca
```

I am calling mypca function from a loop with different values for comp. I am doing this in order to find the best value of comp for the problem I am trying to solve. But mypca function always returns the same value i.e. Xpca irrespective of value of comp.
The value it returns is correct for first value of comp I send from the loop i.e. Xpca value which it sends each time is correct for comp = 10 in my case.

**What should I do in order to find best value of comp?**

Comment: Xpca should have the number of columns = comp. Is this the case independent of what value is passed into mypca()? Try printing the value of comp passed into mypca().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to pass different values for number of components, and re-fit with each. A great thing about PCA is that it's actually not necessary to do this. You can fit the full number of components (even as many components as dimensions in your dataset), then simply discard the components you don't want (i.e. those with small variance). This is equivalent to re-fitting the entire model with fewer components. Saves a lot of computation.

How to do it:

```
# x = input data, size(<points>, <dimensions>)

# fit the full model
max_components = x.shape[1] # as many components as input dimensions
pca = PCA(n_components=max_components)
pca.fit(x)

# transform the data (contains all components)
y_all = pca.transform(x)

# keep only the top k components (with greatest variance)
k = 2
y = y_all[:, 0:k]
```

In terms of how to select the number of components, it depends what you want to do. One standard way of choosing the number of components `k` is to look at the fraction of variance explained (`R^2`) by each choice of `k`. If your data is distributed near a low-dimensional linear subspace, then when you plot `R^2` vs. `k`, the curve will have an 'elbow' shape. The elbow will be located at the dimensionality of the subspace. It's good practice to look at this curve because it helps understand the data. Even if there's no clean elbow, it's common to choose a threshold value for `R^2`, e.g. to preserve 95% of the variance.

Here's how to do it (this should be done on the model with `max_components` components):

```
# Calculate fraction of variance explained
# for each choice of number of components
r2 = pca.explained_variance_.cumsum() / x.var(0).sum()
```

Another way you might want to proceed is to take the PCA-transformed data and feed it to a downstream algorithm (e.g. classifier/regression), then select your number of components based on the performance (e.g. using cross validation).

Side note: Maybe just a formatting issue, but your code block in `mypca()` should be indented, or it won't be interpreted as part of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You use PCA to reduce the dimension.

From your code:

```
for n_comp in range(10,1000,20):
    Xpca = mypca(X,n_comp) # X is a 2 dimensional array
    print Xpca
```

Your input dataset `X` is only a 2 dimensional array, the minimum `n_comp` is 10, so the PCA try to find the 10 best dimension for you. Since 10 > 2, you will always get the same answer. :)

Comment: 2 dimensional array could be the data type (i.e. a matrix), not a dataset with dimensionality 2 (i.e. a matrix with 2 columns)

Comment: Please see the example for iris dataset with shape (150x4), may be inverse the matrix: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html#example-datasets-plot-iris-dataset-py